# Spring Tool Suite: How to hide blue color bottom border of selected file

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-tool-suite, sts

How to hide blue color bottom border of selected file, as shown in the below image, I am using Spring Tool Suite 4.[image]

Comment: @greg-449 where I can find the css file and which css class I need to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no UI to change this, you will have to edit the Eclipse CSS.

The CSS is in the "plugins/org.eclipse.ui.themes_xxxx/css" folder in your Eclipse installation (xxxx varies depending on your Eclipse release).

For the dark theme I think this is probably the `CTabFolder.active` selector in the `e4-dark_tabstyle.css` file:

```css
CTabFolder.active {
    swt-selected-tab-highlight: #316c9b;
    swt-selected-highlight-top: false;
}
```

Comment: greg-449 Thanks a lot, I have removed swt-selected-tab-highlight: #316c9b;  property from CTabFolder.active css class in the directory /Applications/SpringToolSuite4.app/Contents/Eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.ui.themes_1.2.1100.v20200825-0757/css/dark/e4-dark_tabstyle.css (MacOS X), it is working now